# ARM7 print/output function

Tags: compiler-construction, assembly, arm, pascal

I am trying to implement a simple Pascal to ARM assembly compiler. I need to implement the write() function, but I have no idea how to to it in assembler. I tried to google it but without success. I am using Keil uVision 4 to emulate my assembly code.

Lets say I would like to compile the following program:

```
PROGRAM myProg;
var A : integer;

BEGIN

A := 5;
write(A);

END.
```

How would it look like in ARM assembly?

Comment: Depends on what OS you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the integer to a string
2. loop over the string
3. for every character in the string, output it to your output device

You can experiment with the "free pascal" compiler how the assembler looks like, it supports several ARM architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Alex

There are so many factors here... what's the executable target? Some kind of operating system, or raw hardware? If it's an OS, there will be an API available to you, which should do most of the heavy lifting on your behalf.

But even then, that's only half the story. Behind write() is a huge output-handling library that knows how to convert input data into meaningful output :: write() is one of those odd procedures that takes a variable number of untyped parameters and somehow magically makes sense of them all.

As Marco said, you could have a look at FP's assembler output, but I have a feeling you'll get quickly bogged down in a myriad of subroutine calls.

The other option might be to simply take Marco's idea a bit further - can you not just USE Free Pascal? Even if you don't have an OS on the target device, you can still get it to do most of the work for you. You'd doubtless have to supply hooks to stdin and stdout, but other than that FP might be a workable answer?

Answer (score 0):

write() is an operating system thing not a processor instruction thing.  it takes many hundreds to many hundreds of thousands of instructions for an operating system to implement something like that, you have to either target an operating system or create your own, then create an interface from the processor to that operating system, for example you might choose to use the swi instruction to make system calls.

You are going to have better luck to just create a compiler that compiles to the instruction set, alu operations, add, sub, xor, etc.  read and write memory addresses, etc.

Now were you actually asking how to write memory and A is the address in memory?  (my pascal is pretty rusty) then look at your arm instruction set, there are a few/number of different instructions, primarily you will want to look at the str instructions, str, strh, and strb (some arms have an strd).   Since this is your pascal compiler you can make write() do whatever you want so if that is what you were intending start with the str instruction and go from there.

It sounds to me like you need to start by working on your arm assembler, forget about the pascal compiler...THEN, make a pascal compiler that produces assembler code that you do know how to use and write.  If you dont know how to do it in assembler yourself dont let the compiler do it either.